# Interactions in nonlinear chiral theories

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, interactions, non-linear-systems, chirality

When discussing nonlinear realizations of $SU(3)_L \times  S(3)_R$ in Chiral theories, it is usual to introduce the interactions between the baryon  octet ($B$) and some meson matrix $M$ as
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}_{int} = g_8^M \left\{ \alpha [\bar B O B M]_F + (1-\alpha) [\bar B O B M]_D \right\}  + g_1^M \mathrm{Tr} \left( \bar B O B \right)  \mathrm{Tr}\left( M \right) 
\end{equation}
where the anti-symmetric (F) and symmetric (D) terms are defined as:
\begin{equation}
[\bar B O B M]_F = \mathrm{Tr} \left( \bar B O [B,M]]\right)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
[\bar B O B M]_D = \mathrm{Tr} \left( \bar B O \{B,M\} \right) -\frac{2}{3}  \mathrm{Tr} \left( \bar B O B \right) \mathrm{Tr}\left( M \right) 
\end{equation}
Here the term $g_1^M$ is related to the singlet interaction and $O$ is some Dirac structure depending on the meson $M$, for example, $O=\gamma_\mu$ for vector mesons $M=V_\mu$ and $O=1$ for the scalar meson $O=X$.

If the interaction occurs with a meson octet, then $\mathrm{Tr} M = 0$ and the symmetric term reduces to\begin{equation}
[\bar B O B M]_D = \mathrm{Tr} \left( \bar B O \{B,M\} \right)
\end{equation}

My question is: Why is the symmetric part of the interaction defined with the $2/3$ term? It looks intuitive to me to define it only with the anti-commutator (which is the case when we have a matrix octet).

Is this really a definition? Does it have anything to do with the mixing of singlet and octet matrices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is there to ensure that there is ***no*** mixing between the singlet, displayed separately, and the octet, so you do not double count.
The coefficient of $g_8^M$ contains no singlet.

The 3×3 matrix *M* may, in principle, contain an octet part, and an arbitrary, tracefull!, singlet part proportional to the identity. This singlet part cannot contribute to the *F* piece, but can contribute to the anticommutator,
$$
\mathrm{Tr} \left( \bar B O \{B,M\} \right)=2\mathrm{Tr} \left( \bar B O B~M \right)= 2 \mathrm{Tr} \left( \bar B O B \right) \frac{\mathrm{Tr} M}{3},
$$
since you trace over the 3×3  identity matrix.

Now that the octet term has the singlet projected out, you reintroduce the singlet separately, but there is no reason to keep the silly 2/3 factor: it is absorbed in the singlet coefficient.